# Economic Achilles' heels of global financial economy

Tags: macroeconomics, unemployment, commodities

The latest attacks on oil production in Saudi-Arabia highlights the need for risk managers to follow up on possible terrorist targets that can have a global impact on the global financial economy, together with the corresponding degree of vulnerability and political uncertainty involved. More specifically, the translation of such a list in specific stress test scenarios can highlight areas for a company to hedge certain risks. So the question is, what are the current Achilles' heels of our global financial economy and how would you assess the vulnerability?

Comment: [Welcome to Economics Stackexchange](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/175) :). This question seems to be too broad for it to be answered easily on this forum, as there could be many unforeseen weaknesses in our global economic system, but identifying those weaknesses is subjective. For example, most people didn't see the Great Recession coming, or that the real estate sector would precipitate it. Predicting something like that is tricky.

Comment: Well I get that it's kind of broad, but I think it's very good practice to do this exercise. Also, I'm not specifically looking to predict the unforeseeable or black swans but merely to list possible terrorist targets that could have a major impact; rather for simulation purpose than prediction.